# Understanding 人間界単位で

Tags: counters

From the first episode of Death Note:

> 名前のあとに**人間界単位で**40秒以内に死因を書くと そのとおりになる

**Questions:**

1. What purpose is "人間界単位で" ("within human-world units") serving in this sentence?
2. Grammatically, "人間界" is a noun and "位" is a counter. But the thing that's being counted here isn't literally human-worlds, is it?

Comment: I think you might be mis-parsing this -- you've left out the 単.  Try looking up 単位【たんい】 and see if that helps things make more sense for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it refers to Death Note.

1. 人間界単位で modifies 40秒以内に. It says *by human world units (as opposed to the units in Luke's world).* So 人間界単位で40秒以内に means *within 40 seconds (measured) by human world units*. It is a bit odd since it is written in a human language anyway.
2. Grammatically 人間界 modifies 単位 and it could be written 人間界の単位, *the (system of) units of human world*. 単位 here refers to the system of measurement.

Comment: Is 人間界の単位 the the grammatically correct way of writing it, and the の is omitted due to it being informal speech? Or are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: @George - This might interest you: [Compound words and の-particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55735/43676). 人間界の単位 sounds more natural to me.

Comment: @George Both should be fine, like (I think) English *human world units* and *units of human world*.