# What's the correct translation for 'Japanese Student': 'Nihonjin gakusee' or 'Nihonjin no gakusee'?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particles

I have seen both uses in different contexts, but I'm having trouble figuring out in which case to use the 'no' particle!

Comment: Do you mean a student of the Japanese language, or a student who is Japanese?

Comment: @AeonAkechi It makes all the difference, doesn't it? In English we tend to take for granted this level of specificity. The answer would be very different depending on the case.

Comment: Closely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/7810

Answer (score -2):

の it is a particle.
の-to show possession, of etc... refer this link:[enter link description here](https://www.punipunijapan.com/grammar-lesson-3-particle-%E3%81%AE-no/)

eg: japanese student- 日本人学生(nihonjin gakusei)
    student of japan - 日本の学生(nihon no gakusei)

Comment: While you do technically answer the question, it is a little unsatisfying.  Would you mind expanding your answer to explain the usage?  On JLSE, we want our answers not only to help people asking the questions, but also to answer the questions of others with similar questions.

Comment: I also misinterpreted the question at first. I think this is about dropping の.