# Why a compound noun instead of XのY?

Tags: grammar, nouns, compounds

> **視界左上**に固定表示されている細い横線が、わずかにその長さを縮める

from ソードアート・オンライン1アインクラッド

I'm curious to know why the author chose to use this construction instead of 視界**の**左上.

Edit: And unrelated to that, I just noticed that the 固定表示されている construction is interesting too. What's going on there? Would I be right in assuming that these two suru-verbs form a compound too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

画面の左上 and 固定で表示 are something we say very often in the context related to computers, and in such situations people start to drop the particles between the two words. It's similar to how "winter sport", "Hollywood movie", "earth axis" and so on work without any preposition in English. (Although "top left of the screen" won't contract to "screen top left" in English, you can see why 画面の左上 can become 画面左上 more easily.) 視界左上 is less common than 画面左上, but it can safely be understood as an extension of 画面左上 in *SAO*.

Usually you cannot freely drop の before 右, 上, 前, 北 and so on, but when that position is important in a certain context, they suddenly start to work like a "suffix".

- 氷川神社北 (bus stop), 東海大学前 (station)
- ゴール右上 (soccer), ゴール手前 (marathon)
- 夏休み前, テスト前

I'd say 固定 in your example is just a noun (or a no-adjective). The same is true for 連続運転, 夜間走行, 画面共有 and so on.

Related:

- [the omission of an implied "の" creates the appearance of a 四字熟語{よじじゅくご}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/5010)
- [Why isn't 日本料理 written as 日本の料理?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/5010)