# Ellipsis of の particle

Tags: kanji, particle-の, ellipsis

I would like to know if I'm not mistaken:

> When having a series of の-adjectives, it is ok to perform an ellipsis
> of the の particles and create a long kanji compound.

For example: 日本語基本文法辞典, or a sign on a building: 日本美術館。

As far as I know, this should have been: 日本語の基本の文法の辞典 and 日本の美術館。

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/83429/41270

Comment: @LonelyDriver I think this one had a good answer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/15960

Answer (score 2):

The omission of の works great in book names, organization names and such. (Similar things happen also in English, e.g. "United Nations Human Settlements Programme").

But please note that it does not mean you can do the same in ordinary sentences. In ordinary sentences you can avoid too many の's by replacing some of them with other expressions.

Please also read: [the omission of an implied "の" creates the appearance of a 四字熟語{よじじゅくご}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/5010)