# 連体形 and 連用形 prior to nouns

Tags: grammar

> 作り方法
> 作る方法

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Well, 作り{つくり}方｛かた｝ means 'how [something] is made], and 作る｛つくる｝方｛かた｝ means 'somebody who makes something'. They are not similar at all, and I feel this question may be closed for a lack of research effort

Comment: @Angelos I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

作り方法 is simply incorrect. By definition, 連用形 is "connect(連)-verb/adjective(用)-form(形)", and thus it never modifies a noun arbitrarily. 方 in 作り方 is a suffix rather than an ordinary noun. 方 (かた) is not an independent word meaning "method"; it always has to follow a 連用形 to make sense.

However, [a 連用形 sometimes also works as a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010), and [two nouns can be directly combined to form a compound noun with a fixed meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/5010). So there are compound nouns such as 置き時計 ("clock"), 泣き顔 ("crying face"), 食べ物 ("food"), 入れ歯 ("denture"), 吹き矢 ("blowgun") and 押し花 ("pressed flower"). Basically these are fixed compounds that typically have their own entry in dictionaries. You cannot construct similar ones arbitrarily.

Comment: I have a follow up question. For compound nouns, is it always possible to leave out the hiragana? For example, "泣き顔" to "泣顔", "食べ物" to "食物", "空き腹" to "空腹", etc.

Comment: @Will It depends. 置時計 and 入歯 are safe, but 泣顔 looks odd. 食物 and 空腹 will be taken as different kango words (しょくもつ and くうふく).