# Is there a rule of thumb regarding the use of の when using one noun to modify another?

Tags: particle-の, nouns

I wrote 担当先生 in my composition today. I was not confident about it, so I searched BCCWJ 中納言 and found out that 担任の先生 is the most popular way of saying it, and that 担当の先生 is also acceptable to a less degree. But it seems that 担当先生 and 担任先生 are not entirely unacceptable, with respectively 1 hit yielded in the corpus.

[This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/japanese/comments/fs8zeb/combining_nouns/) suggests that maybe there is not a consistent standard for using の between two nouns, but the range of cases it covers is limited. No similar question is found (on my part) on Japanese SE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the omission of an implied "の" creates the appearance of a 四字熟語{よじじゅくご}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19365/the-omission-of-an-implied-%e3%81%ae-creates-the-appearance-of-a-%e5%9b%9b%e5%ad%97%e7%86%9f%e8%aa%9e%e3%82%88%e3%81%98%e3%81%98%e3%82%85%e3%81%8f%e3%81%94) 担当先生 or 担任先生 can be used when space saving is really important (e.g., in a news headline), but otherwise it sounds unnatural.

Comment: Interestingly, 担当教師 is a common compound that works everywhere. See also: [Why isn't 日本料理 written as 日本の料理?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/5010)

Comment: @naruto Thanks. The two posts you pointed to are illuminating, and now I understand that these cases involving omission of の are as conventional as they are idiomatic.