# This fantasy world description: 時の異次元世界

Tags: grammar, translation, interpretation, semantics

Excuse me, I'd like to know if "world with a different time dimension" is an accurate/sufficient translation of 時の異次元世界. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have translated it like `(時の異次元) + 世界`, but 時の異次元世界 comes off to me as `時の + (異次元世界)`. Note that 異次元 and 世界 are directly connected without の, making it [look like a fixed concept](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/5010).

That is, 時の異次元世界 sounds like there are several parallel worlds (異次元世界) with different themes, and 時の異次元世界 is one of such worlds that happens to be related to time. So the more direct translation might be something like "parallel world of time" or "alternate dimension of time".