# Can the particle "no" sometimes be omitted?

Tags: grammar, particle-の

It seems to me that sometimes the "no" that should be between two nouns is omitted. if so, can this be done in any case or are there special cases?

For example, a case where I think there should be a "no" particle is this

> Birusu-sei de shugyō kaishi da!

I translate this as "It's the training's start in Birusu's planet" (correct me if I'm wrong), and if I would have to write this back for me I would add a "no" to read

> Birusu-sei de shugyō no kaishi da!

A similar phrase it's seen to use the "no"

> Gokū wa shugyō no tabi he!?"

Why? Is it optional?

Comment: For consideration, a related question on another site: [Is this an exception in the use of 的?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/151/100). 的, like の, is a genitive case particle. This other question on CLSE might offer insight into our question here at JLSE.

Comment: Probably related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21166/5010

Comment: @naruto you are japanese, right? does it sound unnatural to you saying "Birusu-sei de shugyō no kaishi da!" or it sounds ok? Aside of the reasons why it's right or not to say it so, it's important to know if it's used that way or not in everyday japanese language

Comment: @Flaw Just to clarify: 的 is a genitive particle in Chinese, but not in Japanese.  I want to make sure people don't read the comment and think 的 is a particle in Japanese as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some nouns tend to directly follow arbitrary nouns without any particle and form longer noun phrases. 開始 (kaishi) is one of such nouns, while 旅 is not (although there are several fixed `noun + 旅` compounds). See my previous answer for other examples: [the omission of an implied "の" creates the appearance of a 四字熟語{よじじゅくご}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/5010)

"Birusu-sei de shugyō *no* kaishi da!" is grammatically fine, but I feel this *no* should be omitted. That is partly because this is a subtitle (which should generally be short) and partly because this is a vigorous colloquial sentence where particles tend to be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

No, you basically can't omit it.

Birusu-sei doesn't stand for "Birusu's planet" but "planet Birusu", though it happens to be Birusu's planet (Birusu-no hoshi) too in the story. (The globe is ware-ware no hoshi while it can't be ware-ware-boshi.)

shugyō-kaishi is one compound word and in this case it's almost the same as omission from shugyo-no kaishi but not necessarily interpreted so in every context. For example, it doesn't really work when your mentor says it at the beginning of training.

Comment: so If I learn all compound words I'll know when it goes noun-noun instead of noun no noun?

Comment: Making arbitrary compounds might work to some extent, but it's to some extent.