# Why is 漫画全部の売り上げ grammatical

Tags: grammar, particle-の

> しかし、許可をもらわないでコピーした漫画をインターネットで読む人が増えているため、**漫画全部の売り上げ**は少なくなっています。
>   However, because the number of people who read manga on the internet – that has been copied without permission – is increasing, total manga sales are decreasing.

No problem with understanding (I hope), but 漫画全部の売り上げ looks weird to me. I feel it ought to be 漫画の全部の売り上げ. Is this a typo? If not, why is it okay to write it like this?

Comment: 「リンゴ３個の値段」とかと同じ形ですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

名詞+全部 is almost as common as 名詞+の+全部

Think of it as akin to the difference between ‘All manga’ vs. ‘All of the manga’. There is really no functional difference. If the case for a difference had to be made, it would likely be a slight reduction in formality when not using the particle.

This applies to  全員, 全て, 半分, etc.

```
漫画全部

漫画家全員

料理全て

参加者全員

気持ち半分
```

Two similar expressions, one using の and one without:

> 財産全部、地獄に持って行ける訳じゃない。
>
> その財産の全部を出資するものとする。

Also see: [Can the particle "no" sometimes be omitted?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38748)