# What is the meaning of もちうるもの全て in this context

Tags: meaning

[image]

I am really confused on how to translate もちうるもの全て in the first manga panel. I tried pasting it into some online translators and it said something like "everything that can be used" but shouldn't it be 全てのもちうるもの if that's the case? So what does もちうるもの全て actually mean and how does it fit to the whole sentence?

Edit: Ok, I think I understand now how もちうるもの全て grammatically works. But I'm still a bit confused how does もちうるもの全て works together with the sentence before it (見廻組に反乱勢力) grammatically and how to translate it.

Comment: Related, perhaps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56950/9831 Compare: 「持ちうるもの+全て+を」「漫画+全部+の」「リンゴ+3個+の」

Comment: `見廻組に反乱勢力` Regarding the に: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12188/9831

Answer (score 1):

The pattern [clause] + もの全て means *all (that) [clause]*. So もちうるもの全て means *all that I have (for use)*.

Perhaps you can think it derives from '[clause] もの**の**すべて', which is the basic AのB=B of A and literally *all of what [clause]*.

Other (similar) examples:

- **見るもの(の)全て**が新しい everything I see is new (to me)
- **持っていたお金(の)ほとんど**を使ってしまった I spent almost all the money I had.
- **聞いたこと(の)すべて**を忘れた I forgot everything I heard.

Comment: I see, so 全てのもちうるもの and もちうるもの全て is basically the same thing. One more question, how exactly does もちうるもの全て  fits with the sentence before it (見廻組に反乱勢力) since there isn't really anything to connect the two sentence?

Comment: @asyrafshaari I don't know that part of Gintama, but 見廻組に反乱勢力 should be (all) the speaker has to fight for his(?) purpose.

Comment: Also 全てのもちうるもの is not very idiomatic.