# When can "AのB" be digested down to "AB"?

Tags: nuances, particle-の, register

I sometimes see things like "野の風" be digested down into "野風" or "空の色" into "空色" both while retaining their meanings. When is this allowed to happen? What registers of speech? What sorta relationships? Is it only allowed for set phrases? etc. etc.

Why is 人権団体 not 人権の団体? Why is 人工言語 not 人工の言語? I'm simply curious, I've seen this so often.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21150/5010

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but I haven't the reputation.

I believe what we have here is a case of [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent), rather than any language trouble.

For the sake of argument, let's assume all cases of AのB can be condensed to AB.
This doesn't automatically make everything in the form AB something condensed from AのB, however.
It could have been condensed from AはB*, or simply have been AB to begin with.

Given your example, 人権団体 is likely better expanded to 人権を守る団体.

*This is just a example; I do not claim that such cases actually exist, though I wouldn't be surprised if they do.