# Can you omit the な between な-adjectives and nouns?

Tags: adjectives, na-adjectives

> 書く時には書くスタイルに合った書き言葉的表現、そして、話す時には話すスタイルに合った話し言葉的表現があることを覚えておいてください。

The above quote is from the second chapter of Tobira. My question concerns 書き言葉的表現 and 話し言葉的表現. The book states that (書き/話し)言葉的 is a な-adjective, as are most nouns attached to the 的 suffix. But why has the な been omitted between 言葉的 and 表現? Shouldn't it be 書き言葉的な表現 and 話し言葉的な表現?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21150/9831

Comment: 参考になるかどうかわかりませんが、明鏡国語辞典によると：`てき【的】.. 語法(1) 派生形の連体用法には、「具体的解決法」「具体的な解決法」の二種類があるが、前者がやや文語的。古い言い方には「具体的の解決法」もある。`