# What does 日曜日のお父さん状態 mean?

Tags: meaning

This text is from a light novel:

> ラグニールは既に龍王の座を青い龍へと譲り、隠居の身になっていた。
>
> ただ、それによって今はどこにも居場所が無いと嘆いており、カガネ曰く「日曜日のお父さん状態」らしい。どういう意味なのか知りたいんだけど、聞かない方がいいような気がした……俺も将来そうなるのだろうか……

I don't understand what 日曜日のお父さん状態 is supposed to mean.  I understand the words for "Sunday", "father", and "state", but I can't figure out what this phrase is supposed to mean.

Comment: [This](http://livedoor.blogimg.jp/ayacnews/imgs/6/8/68675ddd.jpg)

Comment: @user27280 that cat is certainly "Like a Dad on Sunday" (hint hint, though it isn't obvious). That being said, one thing that could have helped was more context, in the absence of understanding this bit.

Comment: Please don't leave part of your question in the comment section; instead, make sure you include these kinds of details in the question itself.  If you'd like to add further details, please feel free to [edit] your post.

Comment: @psosuna  Point taken.

Answer (score 2):

日曜日のお父さん状態 is 日曜日のお父さん**の**状態, or "that status/situation of a dad on Sundays". の is (intentionally) omitted because the author implies this expression refers to something every reader knows. See: [-的 adjectives modifying nouns without な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21150/5010)

So the sentence says ラグニール is like a typical Sunday dad. What it exactly means is clearly indicated in the context. 日曜日のお父さん is a metaphor of どこにも居場所が無い (i.e., "I feel like I don't belong here", "I feel isolated"). Many middle-aged Japanese businesspersons are so busy and tired that they often have this feeling on holidays.