# 日本語教室 versus 日本語の教室

Tags: particles, particle-の

I know that it's correct to say 日本語教室, and it's also correct to say 日本語の教室. I am confused by 日本語教室. From my understanding, the particle の connects 2 nouns. For example, さくら大学**の**学生 (there is no particle before `university` because さくら大学 is one name).

Please explain why 日本語教室 is OK. When can I omit の？ And when is it impossible to do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Also realted: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21166/5010