# multiples noun, noun modifiers other noun?

Tags: adjectives

I have a question
multiple nouns ( noun + noun ), noun working as adjective？

Recently, I've been researching noun modifiers, I wonder if multiple nouns can modify one as an adjective?

for example:

> 敵ユニットと言った場合、主に敵チャンピオンと敵ミニオンですかね
>   ペットやタワーを含むかどうかは効果によっては微妙な所ですが、あれもユニットと言えばユニットです

敵（ enemy ) + チャンピオン ( champion ) this is like an adjective, right?

Example:

〇〇なチャンピオン＝形容動詞

奇麗な女戦士が敵チャンピオンにダメージを与えられた　（俺が作ってみた例文）

凄いチャンピオン＝形容詞

美しい女の子を心配させたなんて！　（作ってみた例文）

悪魔ユウキ

天使ユウキ

というわけで　名詞の場合は、最初の名詞は後ろの名詞を修飾する形容詞的な役割を果たすことが多いのですか！？

（In the case of nouns, is the first noun　acting as an adjective to modify the subsequent nouns! ?）

Comment: Also in English, nouns can work *adjectivally*, for example you can say "earth axis", "winter sport", "computer science", "Hollywood movie", "enemy unit", and so on. Please see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19379/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21166/5010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "yes, the first noun is acting as an adjective"

My hesitation ("would") comes from realising that we may be taking about grammatical definitions here (so I don't know how appropriate the "like an adjective" is), but  if someone posted the following question on a Japanese forum that focuses on people "researching" the English language:

Is "business" in "business lunch" acting as an adjective to modify "lunch"?

I think the answer would be the same as that of your question "（In the case of nouns, is the first noun　acting as an adjective to modify the subsequent nouns! ?）"