# オレンジ色のズボンを履きます　vs オレンジ色ズボンを履きます

Tags: word-choice

I came across this simple definition in my lesson, and I was wondering what the difference between these statements is. Both of them have the same meaning, "I wear orange pants". Is it a difference in assignment, or is it negligible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

オレンジ色**の**ズボンを履きます is the right choice. Since オレンジ is a no-adjective, you need to add の to make it modify a noun (ズボン).

Omission of の is allowed only when "オレンジ色ズボン" is presented as an established set phrase. For example, we can say ピンクリボン without の because ["Pink Ribbon" is a set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_ribbon). Please see the following related questions.

- [Why isn't 日本料理 written as 日本の料理?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/5010)
- [-的 adjectives modifying nouns without な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21150/5010)
- [the omission of an implied "の" creates the appearance of a 四字熟語{よじじゅくご}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/5010)