# What is the difference between 人気のある, 人気がある, 人気の, and 人気な?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, nouns, na-adjectives

As 人気 is a noun and な-adjective, it can be used in these phrases:

> 人気**のある**映画
> 人気**がある**映画
> 人気**の**映画
> 人気**な**映画
> 人気映画

To me, they all mean ‘popular movie’, but the first 2 literally mean ‘movie that has popularity’ because of the relative clause. Is there any differences/nuances between these phrases, or are they all identical in meaning?

Comment: As for 人気映画, please see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21150/5010). It can be used in a fixed phrase like 人気映画ランキング, but you usually have to use the other four.