# "no" in "Chōsa Heidan" - Shingeki no Kyojin

Tags: particles, particle-の, manga, anime

In Attack on Titan, Survey Corps Japanese name is (Chōsa Heidan) (調査兵団)

Chōsa (調査) means "Survey" and Heidan (兵団) means "Army Corps'

My question is why are Heidan written directly after Chōsa without a "の" relating them to each other.

To be like (Corps of Survey). I know there's something in English Grammar called Noun Adjunct or Noun Modifier. Which is simply a noun acting as an adjective modifying another noun. Is it the case here or something alike?

Comment: Related: [Why isn't 日本料理 written as 日本の料理?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/5010) / [-的 adjectives modifying nouns without な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21166/5010) / [赤ずきん vs. 赤い頭巾](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93115/5010) It's essentially the same as how "movies of Hollywood" eventually became "Hollywood movies", or how "axis of the earth" eventually became "earth axis".

Comment: @naruto Well in "earth axis" or "hollywood movies" it is either noun modifiers or just possession is not used because both "earth" and "hollywood" are inanimate (I searched a bit on this topic and seems there has been a long debate about the possession of inanimate)

Comment: @naruto Thank you for these related questions. They answer my question for the most part. I understand the concept of saving spaces on headlines or making a certain phrase to use it, but compound nouns? not clearly. In English there are words like "blackboard" or "sunlight". Chousa Heidan doesn't seem to be like these words and it isn't in dictionaries. And the most important question is "can this be considered formal or just common writing"?

Comment: There is no fundamental difference between how 調査兵団 and *Survey Corps* were formed. I'm sure the latter is not in Cambridge English Dictionary, but you understand how it should mean. You can create your own phrase like this as long as you believe it's an important concept repeatedly referred to in your work or field. Even in the most formal situations.