# Which one is the correct way to say autumn wind chimes 秋風鈴 or 秋の風鈴

Tags: word-choice, particle-の

I would like to know how to say "autumn wind chimes." Is it aki fuurin 秋風鈴  or aki no fuurin 秋の風鈴? Or perhaps is it both correct? If it depends on the context I just wanted to say autumn wind chimes as if I said spring wind chimes or summer wind chimes it's not part of any other sentence.

Comment: And in what kind of context would you say spring wind chimes or summer wind chimes? Would there be any particular reason for using those phrases instead of saying wind chimes in spring/summer or wind chimes for spring/summer?

Comment: I just wanted it for a title, it's not part of any sentence , example: music title/video title/logo title,does it help? I like how just the word "autumn wind chimes" as a title sounds, I feel "wind chimes in autumn" or "wind chimes of autumn"  is not the same ...meaning, but Im unsure which one is the correct one for just "autumn wind chimes" and googling it I saw there is a song that is called "aki fuurin " without the particle No. But in the lyrics they also say aki no fuurin. So i was confused and wondered when to use    aki fuurin and aki no fuurin . I hope this help

Answer (score 5):

In English, "Hollywood movie" makes perfect sense, but "Houston movie" is a puzzling expression when used on its own. Likewise, saying 秋風鈴 without の implies you are thinking it is a fixed idea, as a compound word. Generally speaking, 秋風鈴 sounds puzzling because it is not a word Japanese people have recognized.

- [Why isn't 日本料理 written as 日本の料理?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27485/5010)
- [赤ずきん vs. 赤い頭巾 (grammar)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93115/5010)
- [-的 adjectives modifying nouns without な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21150/5010)
- [the omission of an implied "の" creates the appearance of a 四字熟語{よじじゅくご}?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/5010)

So, if you used 秋風鈴 without any context, people are going to ask you, **"What's a 秋風鈴?"** If it is the title of a video with a story, and you can confidently state your definition of 秋風鈴 in one or two sentences, then go ahead and use it for that meaning in your work. If it's a new product name (like "Apple Watch" or "Cup Noodle"), it makes sense, too. On the other hand, if there is no special meaning and it's just some wind chime you saw in autumn, you usually should not omit の.

There is indeed a song titled [秋風鈴](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emxEZIEvWWo) by Maiko Fujita. By intentionally giving a little puzzling title, I feel the lyricist is trying to make you guess the metaphorical meaning of 秋風鈴 here. The audience ask themselves "What is a 秋風鈴?", and they would notice the implication here is "something left behind", or "someone forgotten", because a wind chime is basically a symbol of summer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It helps me understand more!,  I wanted it to be more for a title of a logo or brand  but i want to kept the meaning of it being " wind chimes that are still seen in autumn  even if summer is over",I think it explains it better now what i mean?, Your reply helped me explain it better !  so for what I understand " Aki fuurin" doesn't keep the meaning and it's more to the person to come up with a meaning.  Is it ok to use " Aki no fuurin"  to kept the meaning of  " wind chimes that are still seen in autumn  even if summer is over" when it's said? . Thank you again! 

Comment: @user54624 秋の風鈴 and 秋風鈴 are both valid titles, and essentially mean the same thing in this song. But with the latter, people are more likely to notice the symbolic meaning, because 秋風鈴 strikes people as "unfamiliar".

Comment: Ok! Thank you for all the help !